# Relation between gcd of a set of finitely many polynomials and determinant of matrix valued polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_n$ be $n$ one variable polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[z]$ such that their gcd is $1$ i.e. there exist polynomials $g_1,g_2,...,g_n$, so that $f_1g_1+f_2g_2+\cdots+f_ng_n =1$.

I want to know whether does this guarantee existence of $n^2 -n$ polynomials,  say $u^1_1,u^1_2,..,u^1_n,...,u^{n-1}_1,u^{n-1}_2,...,u^{n-1}_n$, so that

\begin{align}
\det \begin{pmatrix}
    f_1 & f_2 & \cdots &f_n\\
    u^1_1& u^1_2 & \cdots &u^1_n\\
    * & * & \cdots & *\\
    u^{n-1}_1&u^{n-1}_2&\cdots &u^{n-1}_n
    \end{pmatrix} =1
\end{align}

I have already proved the result for $n =2, 3$. But I am not able to prove the result in general.

So, my question is whether above statement is true for arbitrary natural number $n \geq 2$, or not?

If the result is true for all natural number $n \geq 2$, is there any geometric interpretation for the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds for any PID $R$ and $a_1,…,a_n∈R$ with $\gcd(a_1,…,a_n)=1$. For a proof see Theorem 2.2 [here](https://books.google.ro/books?id=RFzdBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=pid+unimodular+%28a1,+...+,+an%29+%3D+1&source=bl&ots=IaodI-NII-&sig=hJrMuJXpeN0OKv-stiaq3etXKq0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAmoVChMIh9HbrMCPyQIVQU4aCh18mwtE#v=onepage&q&f=false).